# How to split this string into separate column in spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, split, spreadsheet

I have the following set of data after download it from the web. The original data is supposed to be Type is "preference", Properties is "Create, Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort, Update" and Description is "ID".

```
TypereferencePropertiesCreate, Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort, UpdateDescriptionID
TypereferencePropertiesCreate, Filter, Group, Nillable, Sort, UpdateDescriptionID of the account associated with this opportunity.
TypecurrencyPropertiesCreate, Filter, Nillable, Sort, UpdateDescriptionEstimated total sale amount.
```

There are online tutorials to teach how to split string by using delimiter such as ", space, or other symbols" in spreadsheet but my set of data is different. How can I split "Type", "Properties" and "Description" out?

Comment: I think we'll have to see some example data on this one since there is no clear pattern here.

Comment: It looks like the *Type*, etc was an *atom* with a custom delimiter like a zero-width space (Unicode 8603 or 200b). The first thing to do is check if you have actually retained the non-visible delimiter or whether a code-page discarded it. Can you check the `LEN(A1)` and see if it seems to properly reflects the visible characters or if it is returning a length that seems too long?

Comment: JNevill, this is the source of the sample. The pattern is all like this. See the updated.  The pattern is Type, Properties, Description.

Answer (score 1):

If there is not a delimiter string, (@Jeeped mentions a zero-width space), then you can use ordinary string functions, like `Mid` and `Instr` to parse this out. I put the output on a new worksheet:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim findType As Integer
    Dim findProperties As Integer
    Dim findDescription As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim newSheet

    Set rng = Range("A1:A3")

    'Add a new sheet and put some header rows on it
    Set newSheet = Sheets.Add
        newSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Type"
        newSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Properties"
        newSheet.Range("C1").Value = "Description"
        i = 1
    For Each r In rng.Cells
        findType = InStr(1, r.Value, "Type")
        findProperties = InStr(1, r.Value, "Properties")
        findDescription = InStr(1, r.Value, "Description")

        '## Print some output values to a new worksheet

        With newSheet
            i = i + 1
            .Range("A" & i).Value = Mid(r.Value, findType + 4, findProperties - (findType + 4))
            .Range("B" & i).Value = Mid(r.Value, findProperties + 10, findDescription - (findProperties + 10))
            .Range("C" & i).Value = Mid(r.Value, findDescription + 11)
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Here is an alternate that puts it on the same worksheet (untested):

```
Sub foo2()
    Dim findType As Integer
    Dim findProperties As Integer
    Dim findDescription As Integer
    Dim typeStr as String, propStr as String, descStr as String

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set rng = Range("A1:A3")

    i = 1
    For Each r In rng.Cells
        findType = InStr(1, r.Value, "Type")
        findProperties = InStr(1, r.Value, "Properties")
        findDescription = InStr(1, r.Value, "Description")

        i = i + 1
        typeStr = Mid(r.Value, findType + 4, findProperties - (findType + 4))
        propStr = Mid(r.Value, findProperties + 10, findDescription - (findProperties + 10))
        descStr = Mid(r.Value, findDescription + 11)
        rng.Value = typStr
        rng.Offset(0,1).Value = propStr
        rng.Offset(0,2).Value = descStr
    Next
    Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
    Range("A1").Value = "Type"
    Range("B1").Value = "Properties"
    Range("C1").Value = "Description"
End Sub
```

Comment: This script works fine. I have one more question. Instead of create a new sheet, is it possible to split them up to the next column of the sample data in the same sheet?

Comment: Yes. Instead of with newsheet, do with activesheet. t this may overwrite data in that sheet so you still may need to modify it a little bit

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have no background with vba.

Comment: I don't really know how to make it any more clear, there's a line in that code it says with newsheet change it to say with activesheet

Comment: Also I'm away from my computer right now so not really going to be able to help her probably a couple hours so you should try and tinker with ot okay

Comment: I added another procedure that should do it on same worksheet.